# Is "Thread starvation deadlock" happening here

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I'm trying to concurrently process some transactions via a web service(through it's Java API), using Callables and a ThreadPool

```
public class CallableTxSender implements Callable<Transaction> {

    private Transaction transaction;
    private Engine engine;

    public CallableTxSender(Transaction transaction, Engine engine) {
        this.transaction = transaction;
        this.engine= engine;
    }

    @Override
    public Transaction call() throws Exception {
        return engine.processTx(transaction);
    }

}
```

Where `Engine` - is the Api that does the web service call.

I'm creating a pool of say 50 threads;

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
List<Transaction> transactions = transactionDao.getPaidTxs();

Engine engine= new Engine();
for (Transaction transaction : transactions) {
    CallableTxSender txSender = new CallableTxSender(transaction, engine);
    executorService.submit(txSender);
}
```

When I try to process 100 transactions, it starts fine with first 20-30 transactions, then somewhere it just hangs. I'm not sure if the API supports simultaneous requests but it should.

What I want to make sure is that my client part is fine. What do you think?

**Edit**: I reduced pool size to 10, and it processes fine. Thanks *Marko* from the comments.
The question still is though, what makes a pool hang with 50 concurrent tasks while not with 10?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It looks like the issue would be in `engine.processTx(transaction)`...

Comment: As a general advice, you will almost certainly fail in improving performance by using that many parallel service calls. I expect performance to level off at or before 10 concurrent requests.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem in the code you have provided.

Instead of guessing where the hang could be I would get a stack trace with `jstack` or `jvisualvm` and find the line and stack trace of the hung threads and which object they are sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Thread starvation deadlock happens when the tasks submitted to an executor service submit other tasks and wait for them to complete.  Nothing in the code in your Question indicates that is happening here.

It is not impossible that some other part of your code is causing thread starvation deadlock, but you should also consider the possibility of other kinds of deadlock.

---

> The question still is though, what makes a pool hang with 50 concurrent tasks while not with 10?

It is not possible to say with certainty.  However one possible explanation is that performing more tasks at the same time increases the probability that a particular locking scenario will occur.  (The analogy is with the birthday paradox ...)

The corollary is that reducing the pool size has dramatically reduced the likelihood of deadlock, but you cannot be *sure* that you have eliminated the problem entirely.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question, would be nice if you could have a look

Comment: Thank you, I see your point, but I'm still puzzled. It do not have control on the API, I'm creating new instance of Engine on each call. I just want to make sure that the API part is responsible for "not being able to handle such number of simultaneous transactions".

Answer (score 0):

If transactions do not depend on each other, then your code is OK. To make sure, use newCachedThreadPool instead of newFixedThreadPool.

Answer (score 0):

[ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) implementation in the java.util.concurrent can help you adjust the Thread pool size, workQueue size and other various extensibility hooks.
Queue sizes and maximum pool sizes may be traded off for each other. New tasks will either wait in the workQueue when all corePoolSize threads are busy or create new threads upto maximum pool size. If both workQueue is full and maximum pool threads are busy then new task submitted to the Executor will be rejected and one of the task rejection policies will come into play. Its important that tasks should be independent of each other when the workQueue size is large.